# hasRole() within th:remove is not working

Tags: java, spring-security, thymeleaf, spring-el

I want to disable a particular link but retain its text, giving it the appearance of being disabled. I am trying to place a th:remove with a certain condition inside the anchor tag. I found this on the ThymeLeaf tutorial page:

```
<a href="/something" th:remove="${condition}? tag">Link text not to be removed</a>
```

Based on that I'm trying to do this:

```
<li>
    <a th:href="@{/config/mod/}"
       th:remove="${#authorization.expression('hasRole(''VIEW_MODULE_STATUS'')')}? tag">
        <i class="fa fa-gear"></i>&nbsp;[[#{webadmin.view.config.module.title.short}]]
    </a>
</li>
```

where VIEW_MODULE_STATUS is the role. The condition does not seem to work and I can't understand why.

FYI: I have used `sec:authorize="hasRole('VIEW_MODULE_STATUS')"` in the anchor tag and it works fine. I want to avoid this approach because it completely removed the text and the link. Is there any other approach to have the link disabled and retain the text using ThymeLeaf?

(I am using ThymeLeaf 3.0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a mistake in the ternary operator being used in the expressions `th:remove="${#authorization.expression('hasRole(''VIEW_MODULE_STATUS'')')}? tag"`

A ternary operator is of form `condition? 'true' : 'false'`. So you have to update your expression. Then you cannot disable an `<a>` tag, the only thing you can do is update its `href` attribute to be `#` or `javascript:void(0);` so that it doesn't have any action. You could do it as shown below:

```
th:href="${#authorization.expression('hasRole(''VIEW_MODULE_STATUS'')') ? '/something' : '#'}"
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I tried it & its not working. Here is my th:ref:

`th:href="${#authorization.expression('hasAuthority(''VIEW_MODULE_STATUS'')') ? @{/config/mod/} : '#'}"`

Comment: You cannot use `@{}` inside `${}`. You would have to write it as: `@{${}}`

Comment: My bad. This didn't work either:

`th:href="@{${#authorization.expression('hasAuthority(''VIEW_MODULE_STATUS'')') ? {/config/mod/} : '#'}}"`

Comment: Why is `{/config/mod}` within `{}`. Just put them between `''` like `/config/mod/`

Comment: Whoa! That worked. This is my final version:
`th:href="@{${#authorization.expression('hasAuthority(''VIEW_MODULE_STATUS'')') ? '/config/mod/' : '#'}}"`

One question though: while hovering over the text, the mouse still looks like a hand, indicating its a link, but, nothing happens when its clicked. Is that normal?

Comment: For the mouse pointer you can do it this way `th:style="|cursor : ${#authorization.expression('hasAuthority(''VIEW_‌​MODULE_STATUS'')') ? 'pointer' : 'default'}"` You can even try to look up for creating a `disabled` cursor and use it in place of `default`

Comment: I have a new problem related to the answer you provided. I'm trying to replace a variable in the URL after using the ternary operator:
`th:href="@{${#authorization.expression('hasAuthority(''UPDATE_USER'')') ? '/config/usermgr/edit/${user.pid}' : '#'}}"`
This is not working and i'm getting a `NumberFormatException: For input string: "${user"`, meaning the {user.pid} is not being treated as an expression but as a value. Is there a work around for this?
I have also used:`th:href="@{${#authorization.expression('hasAuthority(''UPDATE_USER'')') ? '/config/usermgr/edit/' + '${user.pid}' : '#'}}"`

Comment: You can use this `th:href="@{${#authorization.expression('hasAuthority(''‌​UPDATE_USER'')') ? '/config/usermgr/edit/' + ${user.pid} : '#'}}"` Look at how we dont need `''` around the `${}` expressions